# How to show a message to a user?

Tags: plugins, comments, notifications

From a plugin how can I show a message to a user?

Specifically I'd like to show a message to any user after comment submission indicating that their comment was submitted.  My thought was to hook into the `comment_post` action.

However in searching for this I could not find an answer to the more general problem of how to show a message to a user.  The message should be shown to the user a single time regardless of whether they are logged in or not on their next page visit. Similar to drupal's `drupal_set_message` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476351/drupal-display-success-error-message)

Comment: A solution I found using a query parameter to indicate whether to show message: http://wpapi.com/add-message-comments-wordpress/ . Other option seems to be to enable and use sessions

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript if you wanted. So wherever the button click is checked, you could add something like this:

```
<?php
    $message = "Your comment has been submitted";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
?>
```

That is if it is supposed to happen when they click the button - I might be misinterpreting the question.